# Windows 10 wow64 not present

Tags: iis-express, wow64

I need to reinstall IIS Express 10 on windows 10 as it was corrupted and but after much searching I could only find the 32 bit version or an AMD64 bit version.  To install the 32 bit version I have tried amending the IIS windows component to allow 32 bit but this did not work.  I searched and found that I need wow64 enabled witha registry setting of 0 but I have no WOW64 in the registry.  I found a few details of enabling WOW64 using DISM commands but when I input a DISM  command to show the features that are disabled there is no WOW64 feature.

How do I resolve this please?

Comment: First you need to decide the bitness of your Windows installation, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/827218/how-to-determine-whether-a-computer-is-running-a-32-bit-version-or-64 and then you should install IIS Express AMD64 if on Windows 64 bit.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks.  I should have said in my original post - it is Windows 10 64 bit.  I know I am running an Intel processor too so I was assuming the "AMD64" was not compatible or else it would just say "64"!!!!

Comment: It should be named AMD64, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64 as it was invented by AMD.